# How can I use udhcpd to start a dhcp server on more than one nic?

Tags: linux, networking, embedded-linux, dhcp

I have a machine which running embedded Linux system, kernel version 2.6.37. It has a Wifi device and about 3 ethernets.

Now I want to start a dhcp server on this machine and then let is looks like a router. I hope each device connect to this machine via wifi/eth could dhcp to get ip and join in this LAN. These devices will have the same subnet and also could ping each other.

I try to use udhcpd to start the dhcp server. I write the udhcpd.conf as the following:

```
start   192.168.3.2
end     192.168.3.20
interface  wlan0 eth0 eth1 eth2
```

But when I run "udhcpd udhcpd.conf -f", error occurred:

```
udhcpd (v1.20.1) started
udhcpd: max_leases=235 is too big, setting to 19
udhcpd: can't open '/var/lib/misc/udhcpd.leases': No such file or directory
udhcpd: is interface wlan0 eth0 eth1 eth2 up and configured?: No such device
```

I checked the documents for udhcpd of busybox, but I can't find any information to talk about this situation.

Comment: "_Now I want to start a dhcp server on this machine and then let is looks like a router._" Routers don't have the same network on different ports, bridges do. I don't think you are looking to route between networks, but bridge interfaces on the same network.

Comment: You mean the wifi and ethernets on router will be bridged together as a single ethernet? Or maybe it looks like a layer 2 switch?

Comment: Wi-Fi and ethernet are separate protocols. You can bridge ethernet with a transparent bridge (switch), but ethernet and Wi-Fi are bridged with a translating bridge (wireless access point). In either case, you need your PC to run switching software so that it can do layer-2 bridging like learning which MAC addresses are on which ports, running spanning-tree to prevent layer-2 loops, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bridge all interfaces to a bridge, then run `udhcpcd` on the bridge interface.

There is a guide on how to setup bridge

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge

Comment: I'm trying but some other errors occurred. When I try  'ip link add name bridge_name type bridge'  then 'operation not supported' occurred. When I try 'brctl add bridge_name' then 'package not installed' occurred. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Find a linux expert to help you out.